# Catch MQ error code from java

Tags: java, ibm-mq, mq

I am using IBM `MQ` and while putting a message on `queue` and I need to catch the error codes for example :

```
MQJE001: Completion Code '2' Reason '2035'
```

My problem is reading this error code, my java program reads the output by:

```
BufferReader reader = new BufferReader(new InputStreamReader(processSH.getInputStream())); // processSH - the process that is putting message on queue
```

If there are no error codes I can read the output in this way, but I cannot read it using :

```
String line = null;
while(line.reader.readLine()) != null){
    system.out.println(line) // prints nothing in case of error
}
```

Thanks to all helpers!

Comment: Which MQ API are you using to put messages? I don't think you are using the proper MQ classes for Java, because that API throws MQExceptions, which contain the RC.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in this block of code:

```
String line = null;
while(line.reader.readLine()) != null){
    system.out.println(line) // prints nothing in case of error
}
```

I'm not even sure how you got it to compile. `reader` isn't a property of `String`. I think that line should read:

`while(line = reader.readLine()) != null){`

Comment: Trying and posting the result.

Comment: No, I cant catch that exception, my program only read the sh that runs the MQ.

Comment: Let me try, I will post the result.

Comment: @ItsikMauyhas `line.reader` makes no sense and shouldn't compile.

Comment: What is `processSH` in `new InputStreamReader(processSH.getInputStream())`? Without a full picture and a specific error, I'm guessing at what your problem will be. If you can elaborate on what the problem is, it will be easier to solve.

Comment: processSH is the process that interact with the MQ, it prints numbers or error, I'm trying to catch an error like show above. I cant post the code(it is a black box)

Comment: What type of object is `processSH`?

Comment: .sh file that runs jars.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108088/discussion-between-adam-rice-and-itsik-mauyhas).

Answer (score 0):

To catch this kind of `exception` I used :

```
BufferReader errorReader = new BufferReader(new InputStreamReader(processSH.getErrorStream()));
```

`MQ` errors can be `ErrorStream` in some cases.

Hopes that helps, thanks.